# DOS INT 21H Function 0AH in nasm style

Tags: assembly, dos, nasm

I am trying to use nasm to rewrite assembly programs in "IBM PC ASSEMBLY LANGUAGE AND PROGRAMMING" (15th edition) by Peter Abel. And here is the demo on buffering input, given on the page of 144, Chapter 8.

The program is equivalent to the C programming

```
char name[20];
scanf("Name?%s", &name);
/*print the input name in the middle of the screen 25 * 80*/
....
```

My rewrite program is:

```
;file: A08CTRNM.asm
segment data
paralist:
maxlen:     db  20  ;The maximum length of the string will be 20
actulen:    resb 1  ;Which character we have inputed now
buffer:     times 20    db 0    ;The buffer where the string is buffered
;end of paralist
prompt:     db "Name?", "$"

segment code
..start:
    mov ax, data
    mov ds, ax
    mov es, ax
    mov ss, ax
    mov sp, stacktop

    call setCursor
    call input
    call clearScreen
    cmp byte [actulen], 0   ;Name entered?
    je  exit            ;no, exit
    call center     ;set bell and '$' and center
    call displayStr ;Display name
exit:
    mov ax, 0x4c00
int 0x21

segment stack stack
    resb 64
stacktop:

input:
    push ax
    push dx
    mov ah, 09h ;Print the prompt
    mov dx, prompt
    int 21h

    mov ah, 0ah ;Request keyboard
    mov dx, paralist
    int 21h
    pop dx
    pop ax  
    ret

center:
    mov bx, actulen     ;Replace ENTER with BELL
    mov byte [buffer+bx], BELL  ;[buffer+bx] was ENTER, and now is BELL
    mov byte [buffer+bx+1], '$' ;Set display delimiter
    mov dl, [actulen]   ;Locate the center column (40 - strlen / 2)
    shr dl, 1   ;devide length by 2
    neg dl  ;reverse sign
    add dl, 40  ;add 40         (DL:DH  Colume:Row)
    mov dh, 12  ;center row
    call setCursor
    ret

displayStr:
    mov ah, 09h
    mov dx, buffer
    int 21h
    ret

clearScreen:
    pusha
    mov ax, 0600h
    mov bx, 30  ;color attribute
    mov cx, LEFT_CORNER 
    mov dx, RIGHT_CORNER
    int 10h
    ret

setCursor:
    mov ah, 02h
    mov bh, 00h
    int 10h
    ret
```

I compile it under linux with

```
$ nasm -fobj A08CTRNM.asm -o a.obj
```

And link it with the link "tlink.exe" in turbo c 2.0 under dosemu

```
c:\tlink a.asm
```

But the linker complains something

```
Fixup overflow in module A08CTRNM.ASM at CODE:000D, target=000D:0006
Fixup overflow in module A08CTRNM.ASM at CODE:0010, target=0010:0006
Fixup overflow in module A08CTRNM.ASM at CODE:0013, target=0013:0006
Fixup overflow in module A08CTRNM.ASM at CODE:0020, target=0020:0006
```

As I run the executable file "a.exe", something is wrong

```
c:\a ->
                      Name?
Invalid Opcode at 00B1 02A9 0202 001B 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 00
```

Can You tell me how to fix the program?

Comment: Why you're compiling in Linux and linking in DOS?

Answer (score 2):

You have 2 problems with your stack.

1. You initialize `ss` to `data`, not `stack`. Solution: Add `mov ax, stack` before the `mov ss, ax`
2. You declare the stack segment in the middle of your program source, and don't switch back to code segment. This means all the code starting from the label `input` gets put into the stack segment. This is causing the errors that get printed. Solution: move the stack segment to the bottom of the file, or switch back to the code segment.

Answer (score 0):

I think Jester has identified your main problem... but there are others...

1. I know the example in the manual does it, but if you declare your stack correctly - which you do, outside of not switching back to `segment code` (the second `stack` is important!) - DOS will initialize `ss` and `sp` for you. Shouldn't do any harm, but you shouldn't need to do it at all. (you do need to initialize `ds` and `es`, but not `ss:sp`) I don't know why it says that in the manual.
2. In your `center:` subroutine, you do: `mov bx, actulen`. This is the address (offset part of the address) of `actulen`. Adding that to the address of   `buffer`   will point you "out in the woods". You want contents - `[actulen]`. But it's only a byte! So move it into  'bl' , and make sure  `bh`  is clear (you need all of `bx` to form an address). `movzx bx, byte`[actulen]` would do it also.
3. In your `clearScreen:` subfunction, you fail to `popa` after doing `pusha`.
4. I'm not sure that `[actulen]` will ever be zero, even if the user enters nothing. As I recall, `int 21h/0Ah` includes the CR that ends input in the "count" returned - so `[actulen]` would be 1, not 0. (a rather minor problem)

If you want to do your linking in Linux (but for a DOS program), Anthony Williams' Alink can be built for Linux. It requires some changes to the source code. You're probably better off using Tlink in DosBox, but it can be done in Linux if you want to.

Your post says you're trying to link the .asm file, but I think that's just a "posto".

Happy assembling!